# Unexpected token return in Render function . React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Getting "Unexpected token" on return in render

```
render() {
   return (
```

Cannot understand why this is happening. I have curly braces in the function inside render ?!

```
export class NoteList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   state = {cnt: 0}
}

componentDidMount() {
   this.state.cnt = 0;
}

appendNoteToDiagram = (note, index) => {

   this.state.cnt++;
   let xpos = this.state.cnt;
   let ypos = this.state.cnt * 60;
   return (<Note x-position="{xpos}" y-position="{ypos}" width="100" 
            height="50" stroke-color="red" fill-color="red" text=" 
            {note.text}">);
 }

 render() {
   return ( // <<<<<< Error Here
       { this.props.notes.map((note, index) => (
           return appendNoteToDiagram(note, index)
       ))}
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the full error message? "Unexpected token '(' on line 10" vs "Unexpected token '{' on line 11" would make a difference in this case

Comment: What's the actual unexpected token? Can you provide the full error please, and which character/line is it referring to?

Comment: You've got some extra `{}` braces there, looks like to me. If you want to return an array, just return it. No need for the `(` that does nothing, or the `{` which is trying to start an object literal probably. You don't need to use the `{}` to escape `<jsx>` land when you're not using any jsx.

Answer (score 1):

Put this JSX inside div.

```
<div>
{ this.props.notes.map((note, index) => (
       return appendNoteToDiagram(note, index)
   ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Or `<React.Fragment>`

Comment: React.Fragment is also fine better way.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `(` instead of `{`, which doesn't make sense because you're calling a function. Ideally, because of `appendNoteToDiagram` function signature, I'd change this:

```
  return (
       { this.props.notes.map((note, index) => (
           return appendNoteToDiagram(note, index)
       ))}
   );
```

To this:

```
  return (<>{this.props.notes.map(appendNoteToDiagram))}</>)
```